# The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I've been struggling hard with trying to read the connection string out of appsettings.json in my MVC app.  I've done it before with scaffolding, but this project I'm not using scaffolding.

Here's my model.  I borrowed the context part from a previous scaffolding project so that might be wrong:

```
public class Query
{
    [Required]
    public Banks Bank { get; set; }        
    
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    
    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class QueryContext : DbContext
{
    public QueryContext()
    {
    }

    public QueryContext(DbContextOptions<QueryContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Query> Queries { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlconn");
            services.AddDbContext<QueryContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

Here's my controller

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
...
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlconn")))
```

The previous line of code is where i'm getting the error:

> The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I DID use scaffolding. Similar situation as you, but I'm trying to reference in a model. I upvoted your question.